# Wordpress page shows content from the previous loop (wp_reset_postdata not working?)

Tags: wordpress

I am rather new to Wordpress, and I can't really get what is going wrong in my example.

In my template I have `page-standard.php` which has a Slider in the Header working by means of the following code:

```
    <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__wrapper">
        <?php
            $posts = get_posts( array(
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'category_name' => 'slidertop',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'include' => array(),
                'exclude' => array(),
                'meta_key' => '',
                'meta_value' =>'',
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'suppress_filters' => true, 
                ) );
            foreach( $posts as $post ){
                setup_postdata($post);
            ?>
<!-- ! Here goes SLIDE content -->
... <!-- ! End of SLIDE content -->
                    
    <?php
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();                    
    ?>
```

And it works fine. But then I need to show contents of the page and make another wp loop on the same page this way:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Standard Page
*/
get_header();
?>

<section class="blog-posts-section">
<div class="container">
<?php
        while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
           get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
        endwhile;
    ?>
</div>      
</section>

<?php
    get_footer();
?>
```

`content.php` looks as follows:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<div class="entry-content">
<?php
    the_content();
?> 
</div>
</article>
```

So it should be showing the contents of the page which has the Page Standard template.

But instead it shows the contents from the SLIDER which it got in the very first wp loop. It seems like `wp_reset_postdata()` is not working properly. I used the same approach before, but just now it started to show this kind of behaviour.

I've tried using `wp_reset_query()` as well, but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just use proper methods provided by Wordpress to run an extra query instead of $posts = get_posts. The code should look like that:

```
<?php 
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>



<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
 
    <!-- pagination here -->
 
    <!-- the loop -->
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- end of the loop -->

<!-- pagination here -->



 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
 
<?php else : ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
```

and then your standard query. It's all described in details in here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/